# How to default to information if none is given using optparse

Tags: ruby, default-value, optparse

I have a program that creates emails, what I want to do is when the `-t` flag is given and no argument is given with the flag, default to something, instead it outputs the usual: `<main>': missing argument: -t (OptionParser::MissingArgument)`

So my question being, if I have this flag:

```
require 'optparse'

OPTIONS = {}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-t INPUT', '--type INPUT', 'Specify who to say hello to'){ |o| OPTIONS[:type] = o }
end.parse!

def say_hello
  puts "Hello #{OPTIONS[:type]}"
end  

case
  when OPTIONS[:type]
    say_hello
  else
    puts "Hello World"
end
```

and I run this flag without the required argument `INPUT`how do I get the program to out put the `Hello World` instead of the: `<main>': missing argument: -t (OptionParser::MissingArgument)`?

Examples:

```
C:\Users\bin\ruby\test_folder>ruby opt.rb -t hello
Hello hello

C:\Users\bin\ruby\test_folder>ruby opt.rb -t
opt.rb:7:in `<main>': missing argument: -t (OptionParser::MissingArgument)

C:\Users\bin\ruby\test_folder>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that by adding brackets around the `INPUT` I can provide the option to provide input examples:

```
require 'optparse'

OPTIONS = {}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-t [INPUT]', '--type [INPUT]', 'Specify the type of email to be generated'){ |o| OPTIONS[:type] = o }
end.parse!

def say_hello
  puts "Hello #{OPTIONS[:type]}"
end  

case 
  when OPTIONS[:type]
    say_hello
  else
    puts "Hello World"
end
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\bin\ruby\test_folder>ruby opt.rb -t
Hello World

C:\Users\bin\ruby\test_folder>ruby opt.rb -t hello
Hello hello
```

So if I do this:

```
require 'optparse'

OPTIONS = {}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  opts.on('-t [INPUT]', '--type [INPUT]', 'Specify the type of email to be generated'){ |o| OPTIONS[:type] = o }
end.parse!

def say_hello
  puts "Hello #{OPTIONS[:type]}"
  puts
  puts OPTIONS[:type]
end  

case 
  when OPTIONS[:type]
    say_hello
  else
    puts "Hello World"
    puts OPTIONS[:type] unless nil; puts "No value given"
end
```

I can output the information provided, or when there's no information provided I can output `No value given`:

```
C:\Users\bin\ruby\test_folder>ruby opt.rb -t hello
Hello hello

hello

C:\Users\bin\ruby\test_folder>ruby opt.rb -t
Hello World

No value given
```